# Is it possible to make a copy of MYSQL table from one of my Droplet to another?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I have my server on Digital Ocean... does anybody know if
is it possible to make a copy of MYSQL table from one of my Droplet to another?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) is your friend. Depending upon your requirements, you may find that [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) is your friend too.